# jQuery datatable highlight single row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to highlight a single row in my jQuery datatable.

I attempted to use the information here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

Using that, I can use Chrome's inspector and I can verify that the class is being added to the table row. But the row is not being highlighted.

Here is the jQuery:

```
 // not sure if this was necessary to show
 $('#example1').DataTable({
   "iDisplayLength": 25,
   "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]],
   "scrollY": 550,
   "scrollX": true,
   "bDestroy": true,
   "stateSave": true
 });

 var table = $('#example1').DataTable(); 
 $('#example1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function()
 {
   if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
     $(this).removeClass('selected');
   }
   else{
     table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
   }
 });
```

With this, as stated, I can see the class being added to the row, I'm just not seeing the row color change.

I added some CSS on the HTML page to see if it would work.  As follows:

```
 <style>
   .selected tr {background-color: blue;}
 </style>
```

To no avail. Does anyone see my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test this, but the error seems to be in the CSS selector you're using for the `background-color`.

It should be `tr.selected` (a `tr` element with the class `selected`) and not `.selected tr` (a `tr` element in an element with the class `.selected`).

Comment: wait - it did work.  I had to remove the classes table-hover and table-striped from the table though.  But I got the row to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are loading `jquery.dataTables.min.css`.

Comment: it appears I am not.  Let me add that and see what happens.

Comment: I already have datatables.min.css loaded.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the jQuery `click` function and a little JS logic track

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/mbLnrcg6/